# PHPUnit - Should we set environment variables explicitly in Unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, environment-variables, phpunit, github-actions

We have Github actions set for PRs to automatically run Unit tests and reject merge if any test fails.

I added an additional environment variable in a new PR, and the Github action does not pick this new environment variable as it doesn't exist in the main branch.

It got me thinking since Unit tests should run as independently as possible, do we explicitly set the $_ENV values, somewhere in the `setUp` possibly?

Comment: Can you please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, what do you mean with "Github action does not pick this new environment variable"?

Comment: I think you've answered your question by yourself already. A unit test will not run any other files. So if your env var is set somewhere other than the file you're testing, it will not be set. So indeed, you will have to do that in the setUp function to mock the behaviour of the env var being set.